# Clone an Undirected Graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I was reading an article on [Clone an Undirected Graph](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/clone-an-undirected-graph/), It says I have do do bfs and have to keep track of visited/cloned nodes.

I have another approach- I will initialize an empty adjacency list and then traverse the original adjacency list and copy it. Its time complexity is O(V+E) and I don't have to keep track of anything.

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Comment: No, that's a perfectly fine approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that you are only given a source vertex and not given the whole adjacency list, then this method won't work.